# Shared files to bytes array

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I use this function to convert file to bytes array:

```
Public Function ConvertToBytes(ByVal path As String) As Byte()
        Dim _tempByte() As Byte = Nothing
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) = True Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("File not exist", path )
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Try
            Dim _fileInfo As New IO.FileInfo(path )
            Dim _NumBytes As Long = _fileInfo.Length
            Dim _FStream As New IO.FileStream(path, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
            Dim _BinaryReader As New IO.BinaryReader(_FStream)
            _tempByte = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(_NumBytes))
            _fileInfo = Nothing
            _NumBytes = 0
            _FStream.Close()
            _FStream.Dispose()
            _BinaryReader.Close()
             Return _tempByte
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

It's all working all right when file is not shared but when files are shared I go to exception from this code line:

```
Dim _FStream As New IO.FileStream(path, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
```

What is problem with my function?

Thanks!

Comment: What exception are you getting? Can you post it as well?

Comment: My code catch exception I go to exception and function  Return Nothing.

Comment: Definitely go with @danbystrom's second answer but when you're debugging its okay to comment out the try/catch so you can see the exception. Or at least log the results of the exception somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said that FileStream should allowed to be shared. There's a separeate overload for that:

```
FileStream(String, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare)
```

But wouldn't it be easier to use the built-in method for this:

```
IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String)
```